# Real-time stores stock MVC application using redis - ejs - express.js

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, redis, ejs

I am building a MVC application of a real-time stores stock application, where: the model is redis, the views is the template engine - ejs, and the controller is express.js.

I have built already the routes and the views, but I find it's hard to define the model.
In the model package I have written the connection to the redis local docker server, as well as some functions that will return the stock amount of a product based on the store name and the product name and another function which return the list of stores name. This data is crucial for some charts I am updating in the ejs files. Therefore, in a certain ejs file I am rendering the page with multiple data in the json. For example, I have a store.ejs file which requires the stores name and also the products amount. Hence, in the store.js controller file I am rendering as following:

```
res.render("pages/stores", {storesName: storesName, productsAmount: productsAmount})
```

Before rendering the page I have to extract the data from my redis server, however, since these get redis methods return a promise, I can't really extract all of them but only one - making only get request from the redis server. So I am sure that this isn't the correct way to do so.

Therefore, I will be glad to see what you think about that.

Thanks!